# Google Directory Admin API in "Try it now" and "API explorer", always returns "Bad request"

Tags: google-api

If I try API request for other APIs, it seems to work fine, or at least - return meaningful error responses.

But for Admin API, it always returns "Bad request", e.g.: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/customer/m/admin/directory_v1/directory.domains.list

I have set up all API access permissions, and still - no luck.
e.g.:
this request (with my correct Google Apps domain name)

[image]

Always returns:

400 OK

```
- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the place, where I finaly found a solution. Step-by-step instruction, I could not find anywhere else. The trick is in correct variable values:

[How to Change Primary Domain in Google Apps](http://www.internetearnings.com/how-to-change-primary-domain-in-google-apps/)

From The Source:

1. Login to your Google Apps Control Panel.
2. Browse to [Google Apps API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/customers/update) Page where you change customer information. Make sure you see your Admin email address in to right corner.
3. Click “**Try it now**” link.
4. In “customerKey” field enter “**my_customer**“.
5. In “fields” field enter “**customerDomain**“.
6. Click “**Request body**” field, a drop down box will appear & select “**customerDomain**“.
7. In the newly appear field, **enter your Secondary Domain which you want to change to Primary Domain**.
8. Finally click the blue “AUTHORIZE AND EXECUTE” button.

When the process is done, your secondary domain is converted to Primary Domain and vise versa.